# Removing old parameters from ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, parameters

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.2.

I have a ModelBuilder with parameters. I ended up removing some and then adding different parameters, but somehow ModelBuilder is still referencing the old parameters.

Even if I delete everything in the model, save and reopen the model, or restart Pro, these parameters still seem to get referenced.

[image]

[image]

Where does ArcGIS Pro store these parameter references and how can I remove them?

Comment: If you export your model to python script before and after your changes and after saving, do the scripts change?